# How to add milliseconds to the timestamp to get the next time

Tags: java

I am getting a time stamp value from table in this format `2015-01-08 17:53:06`.
I need to add some time to it, to scheduled a job. that is add time in milliseconds how can i do that.

example :

```
2015-01-08 17:53:06 +180000
```

that is 30 minutes, how can i achieve it?

Comment: What's the data type of your time stamp? String?

Comment: in database its timestamp and in java model class I have declared it as string

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `java.sql.Timestamp`? Also, are you using Java 8?

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is still searching for a short answer:
Add the new milliseconds to the epoch milliseconds of the timestamp

Like: **`new Timestamp(timestamp.getTime()+30*60*1000);`**

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-07-07 10:10:26");
    Long milliseconds = timestamp.getTime()+30*60*1000;
    Timestamp updatedTimestamp = new Timestamp(milliseconds);
    System.out.println("Updated timestamp: " + updatedTimestamp);
  }
```

Output:
Updated timestamp: 2020-07-07 10:40:26.0

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long laterDate = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int millisec = 18000;

        Timestamp original = new Timestamp(laterDate);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(original.getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, millisec);
        Timestamp after = new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());

        System.out.println(original);
        System.out.println(after);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get date as an argument to the method and I need to add milliseconds for that data it may also change the day for that argument by adding milliseconds . I think getting current time and adding milli seconds would not solve my issue.